# Получить ответ от удалённой машины о завершении действия

Tags: python-3.x, ssh, paramiko

Всем привет.
В работе используется рабочая станция и удалённая машина. В процессе работы используется коннект по ssh для различных действий. Решил слегка упростить себе жизнь и написать небольшой скрипт для работы с удалённой машиной. За неимением более удобных аналогов выбрал модуль парамико. Суть скрипта в следующем: ввёл команду, что я хочу, он сам делает коннект, сам делает, что потребовали, сам отключается, а я при этом пью чай с довольным видом. Подключиться к машине проблем не составляет. А дальше начинаются небольшие трудности.

Пример проблемы. Я хочу распаковать билд (.tar.gz-шник) на удалённой машине. В повседневной жизни - это просто команда на удалённой машине:

```
tar -zxf <%archive name%>
```

При работе с парамико - это:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('tar -zxf <%archive name%>')
```

Проблема данного подхода в том, что архив может быть увесистым (от 500 мб до 20 гб). Соответственно, распаковка занимает от нескольких секунд, до нескольких минут. Проблема в том, что скрипт на локальной машине отработал - он послал себе команду и пошёл выполняться дальше. Но на удалённой машине действие не закончилось и распаковка в процессе. И все команды, посылаемые скриптом, не воспринимаются удалённой машиной. Поставить таймер ожидания скрипта - не вариант, потому что архивы разные и невозможно точно знать, займёт действие 5 секунд или 15 минут.

Собственно вопрос: можно ли как-то получить ответ от удалённой машины, что действие завершилось (архив распаковался и тому подобное) и как это сделать? Через stdout или как-нибудь ещё?

Comment: может вам стоит попробовать использовать [ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_getting_started.html), вместо того, чтобы писать его заново и с нуля? ;-)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34181078/4827341

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При помощи ссылки в комменте выше немного изменил свой подход:

```
host = ''
user = ''
password = ''
port = 22
command = 'tar -zxf <%remote_path%>'

# connection initialization
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(hostname=host, username=user, password=password, port=port)

channel = client.get_transport().open_session()
channel.get_pty()

channel.exec_command(comment)

# waiting for response
print('In progress...')
while True:
    pass
    if channel.exit_status_ready():
        break
print('Done!')

channel.close()
client.close()
```